# Return most recent time in series of creationTimes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Not entirely sure how I word the question but my problem is Im doing an api call that returns a bunch of messages that have a creation time, now what I want to do is only return the latest creationTime for the messages with the same date so say If I have 30 messages on the 15/03/2018 I want to grab the latest time, and discard the rest.. and do that for each set of messages with the same date

So what Ive done so far is..

using lodash I have gotten all the messages, filtered out all the ones with a certain type, and I have ordered them by creationTime so the latest being at the top and going down.. now my question is how can I then make an array of the latest times for each date??

```
this._activityServiceProxy.getAllItems(start, end).subscribe(result => {
        // this.messages = result;
        // console.log(result);
        let loginUnfiltered = _.filter(result, {'title': 'LOGIN'});
        let loginFiltered = _.orderBy(loginUnfiltered, {'creationTime': 'desc'});
        console.log(loginFiltered);
});
```

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map(...)` to get at array of only the latest `creationTime`:

```
this._activityServiceProxy.getAllItems(start, end).subscribe(result => {
        // this.messages = result;
        // console.log(result);
        let loginUnfiltered = _.filter(result, {'title': 'LOGIN'});
        let loginFiltered = _.orderBy(loginUnfiltered, {'creationTime': 'desc'});
        const creationTimes = loginFiltered.map(l => l.creationTime);
        console.log(creationTimes);
        const latestTime = creationTimes[0];
        console.log(latestTime);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Underscore's `groupBy` function to achieve this:

```
const groups = _.groupBy(loginFiltered, (login) => {
    const asDate = new Date(login.creationTime);
    asDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return asDate;
});
Object.keys(groups).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(groups[key][0]);
});
```

You group by the `creationDate` property but remove the time component so all days get grouped together. You then loop through the result and just take the first entry per day.

Note that this assumes your `creationTime` property is a string, as it came from an API. If it's already a date, you don't need the `new Date` line.